# Is there a way to fetch Response header for InvokeRest Method of Powershell Version 5

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-v5.1

How can I fetch Response header for InvokeRest Method of Powershell Version 5, 
For Powershell version 6 -ResponseHeadersVariable is available , Is there any way to do it in powershell version 5. I am unable to find any way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to get response headers of `Invoke-RestMethod` in v5 but you can easily replace that with something like

`$headers = Invoke-WebRequest 'example.com' | select headers`

Adding some context of your scenario can help to suggest more suitable approach.

Comment: Thanks @Denys, Invoke-WebRequest method worked, Actually i was searching for Invoke-RestMethod only that's why could't find any thing. Again Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I am using powershell core and Invoke-RestMethod now has a parameter for getting response headers.

```
♥ pwsh::github$ $null = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://google.com -ResponseHeadersVariable rh
♥ pwsh::github$ $rh
Key                                 Value
---                                 -----
Date                                {Tue, 15 Aug 2023 21:43:50 GMT}
Cache-Control                       {max-age=0, private}
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only {object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script
...........
```